# lookup distance of a vector among 25 million vectors

Tags: c++, linux, vector, distance, nearest-neighbor

I have 25 million high dimensional vectors (e.g. 2000 dimensions),
what is an efficient system that where I can index those vectors,
and then pass in a new vector and get back the K nearest vectors?

I will be running it on a linux system.

Comment: Just to clarify; I was looking for a ready made tool for this, it feels like there should be something ready out there to use so that I would not have to code it myself

Comment: I doubt that there's something already made to cope with 20 million vectors of 2000 dimensions.  I'm more in the opinion that most probably your problem is bad designed and you don't need to do that.  You are talking of processing around 50,000,000,000 numbers.  In floating point that means over 200,000,000,000 bytes storage.  Probably you are facing one instance of the XY problem.  Most probably.

Comment: By the way, for the question to be well formulated here, you should provide code and some example data of a failure case.  Or the question is only opinion based and requesting for some hint about proceeding, in which case it should be closed.  Edit your question and state precisely the problem you are dealing with, providing code and sample data.

Comment: With 2000 dimensions, distance becomes pretty much meaningless. Just take 5 random vectors and compare their mutual distance, you will find that their mutual distances are almost identical.
Of course you could turn that into an efficient algorithm, just compare your search point with, say, 100 vectors and return the 'closest' vector. With a small margin of error, this will be the closest vector you are likely to find in the set of 25 million.

Comment: See also this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99171/why-is-euclidean-distance-not-a-good-metric-in-high-dimensions).

Answer (score 0):

You can make an index of n-dimensional angle with respect to an n-dimensional axis. That will take **O(n)** time then you can sort those with your preferred sort in min of **O(nlogn)** time. I guess then the searching would be in **O(logn)** time to take out the k vectors **+ x** (The amount of work done). I don't think a short-cut exists to such a kind of a problem.

Comment: In my opinion, you don't need a perfect sort to solve this problem. What about using the partial_sort stl algorithm http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partial_sort/ ? Then your vector is sorted in o(n log(k)) complexity. This, however, means that you have to sort your n vectors everytime you need to know which ones of them are nearest neighbors to your new vector. Sorting a vector means moving around its elements which may not be efficient. I don't know how performance-consuming such an operation is with such vectors.

Comment: Sorry Susan as I don't think there are general solutions to problems as specific as yours and you will have to write the code yourself and Lauren I don't understand what is the basis of your sort (i.e. what exactly are you comparing while sorting?) that requires moving around the elements of the vector. Please clarify this.

Comment: I assume the n = 25 mio vectors are stored in an stl container. When you apply an stl sort algorithm, you modify your container by swapping its elements.

Comment: And during the sorting, what I compare is the distance of vector i to the new vector with the distance of vector j to the new vector